# Comparing geometry of two features to get changes using ArcObjects and c#?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, geometry

I would like to compare the geometry between two feature, Already I selected the two feature. How do I start the comparison?

depend on the image below I need to write code to compare this two features and get the difference (blue colour is different) and save the difference in a new feature class,

```
ITopologicalOperator2 pTopOpOld = oldFeature.ShapeCopy as ITopologicalOperator2;
ITopologicalOperator2 pTopOpNew = newFeature.ShapeCopy as ITopologicalOperator2;

IGeometry differenceGeometry = pTopOpOld.Difference(newFeature.Shape);

pTopOpOld = differenceGeometry as ITopologicalOperator2;
pTopOpOld.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;
pTopOpOld.Simplify();
newFeature.Shape = pTopOpOld as IGeometry;
newFeature.Store();
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: The code you have added does not look like an attempt to solve the problem, and is missing too much to be of use as the basis for an answer. I've seen lots of ArcObjects questions here of late, but no answers, which makes me think this question would be more usefully asked in GeoNet (once it's structured as a function with enough declarations to make sense)

Comment: Does the code you posted work or does it error? If it errors whats the error message?

Comment: It was working but with logical error, I added the correct code below please see it, If you have any comment tell me, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();
        IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace1 = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(shapeFileName, 0);
        IFeatureClass featureClass1 = featureWorkspace1.OpenFeatureClass("geometryChanges");

        IFeatureBuffer feature = featureClass1.CreateFeatureBuffer();
        #region Catch New and compare with old

        ITopologicalOperator2 pTopOpNew = newFeature.ShapeCopy as ITopologicalOperator2;
        IGeometry differenceGeometry = pTopOpNew.Difference(oldFeature.Shape);

        feature.Shape = differenceGeometry;

        UpdateFieldValuesToChanges(featureClass1, feature, uniqueId, "GAINED");
        #endregion

        #region Catch Old and compare with new

        IFeatureBuffer featureOld = featureClass1.CreateFeatureBuffer();
        ITopologicalOperator pTopOpOld = oldFeature.ShapeCopy as ITopologicalOperator;
        IGeometry differenceGeometryO = pTopOpOld.Difference(newFeature.Shape);
        featureOld.Shape = differenceGeometryO;
        UpdateFieldValuesToChanges(featureClass1, featureOld, uniqueId, "REDUCED");
        
        #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [difference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Difference_Method/002m000003vr000000/) but what you really want is [Symmetric Difference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/SymmetricDifference_Method/002m000003w1000000/) (the bits of both input features that *aren't* common). Look at the pictures in both links, they will help you understand what each method does.

```
ITopologicalOperator2 pTopOpOld = oldFeature.ShapeCopy as ITopologicalOperator2;
// ITopologicalOperator2 pTopOpNew = newFeature.ShapeCopy as ITopologicalOperator2; // Not used.

IGeometry differenceGeometry = pTopOpOld.Difference(newFeature.ShapeCopy );// always use shapecopy or bad things can happen

pTopOpOld = differenceGeometry as ITopologicalOperator2;
pTopOpOld.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;
pTopOpOld.Simplify();
newFeature.Shape = pTopOpOld as IGeometry;
newFeature.Store();
```

This of course has some assumptions:

1. Both geometries are polygon.
2. newFeature is a new [IFeature](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002q9000000) created with its [IFeatureClass.CreateFeature](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002sz000000) and not an [IFeatureBuffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureBuffer_Interface/0025000002qm000000/) created by [IFeatureClass.CreateFeatureBuffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/CreateFeatureBuffer_Method/0025000002t0000000/), which needs to be inserted on an [insert cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Insert_Method/0025000002t7000000/), not [stored](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007wv000000), if you try to store an IFeatureBuffer object you will get a *method not found* error.

Comment: I solved my issue in below code,If you have any comment please advise